# Yii Relations Active Record with primary key

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, foreign-keys, relationship

I have two tables:

Student

id, name, email, etc..

Subject (It has a foreign key student_ibfk_1)

id, student_id, subject_id, marks

I have both my models defined:

```
class Student extends CActiveRecord{

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
    ....
    ....
    public function relations()
    {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'subjectMember' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Subject', array('id'=>'student_id')),
    }
}

class Subject extends CActiveRecord{

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
    ....
    ....
    public function relations()
    {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'subjectMember' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Student', 'student_ibfk_1(id)'),
    }
}
```

I want to use relations to fetch marks for a student for a subject using AR model.

I am calling this as:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition='`t`.`name`=:name AND `eventMember`.`subject_id`=:subject_id';
$criteria->params=array(':name'=>$name, ':subject_id'=>$subject_id);
$avc = Student::model()->with('subjectMember')->fetchAll($criteria);
```

And I receive an error.

**preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given**

Can you tell me, where am I going wrong? I am following the Yii documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail

**EDIT1**: I also tried

class Student extends CActiveRecord{

```
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
    ....
    ....
    public function relations()
    {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'subjectMember' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Subject', 'subject(student_ibfk_1)'),
    }
}

class Subject extends CActiveRecord{

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
    ....
    ....
    public function relations()
    {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'subjectMember' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Student', 'id'),
    }
}
```

This gives me the error:

**The relation "subject" in active record class "Subject" is specified with an invalid foreign key. The format of the foreign key must be "joinTable(fk1,fk2,...)".**

Comment: It's not clear to me what the relations are. A Student has many Subjects right? And a Subject belongs to a Student? Or does a Subject belong to many Students?

Comment: I agree with chris, are you sure you didn't forget there is not 3 tables instead of 2, one for the join between Subject and Student holding the mark?

Answer (score 1):

You have to name the foreign key field, not the foreign key name. So it should be

```
return array(
    'subjectMember' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Student', 'id'),
}
```

but you can leave the `id` out because it defaults to `id`:

```
return array(
    'subjectMember' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Student'),
}
```

It's easier to create all the foreign relations in mysql and then create the models with gii. It will create all the relation for you.

Comment: However, this does not solve the problem. still the same error.

Comment: Thanks. I have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class Student extends CActiveRecord{

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
    ....
    ....
    public function relations()
    {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'subjectMember' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Subject', 'student_id'),
    }
}

class Subject extends CActiveRecord{

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
    ....
    ....
    public function relations()
    {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'subjectMember' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Student', 'id'),
    }
}
```

Both of your relations were wrong.

Then in your criteria you are calling `eventMember.subject_id`

```
$criteria->condition='`t`.`name`=:name AND `eventMember`.`subject_id`=:subject_id';
```

But nowhere I see the table `eventMember`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I have found the solution.